# Matlab to Python Code

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have piece of code in matlab:

```
Tf=eye(2);
Tb=eye(2);
Tt=eye(2);

n=250;

f=zeros(2,n);


for i=1:n
    f(:,i)=Tf*f(:,i-1);
end
```

I tried to change it to Python code:

```
Tf=eye(2)

n=250

f=numpy.zeros((2,n))

for i in range (n)

    f[:,i]=numpy.dot(Tf, f[:,i-1])
```

this gives "TypeError: **array**() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Any help?

Comment: Post your python attempt as well

Comment: Very hard to help since you chose to conceal the Python code. It's really no fun trying to guess what you wrote.

Comment: Also, "just doesn't work" is pretty vague.  What doesn't work about it?  the more details you give, the better.  e.g. what you expect to get, what you actually get, the full traceback from any exceptions that it raises, etc.

Comment: If you want a 1 to 1 translation, you could try : http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users and then post your Python code in case it does not work

Comment: I added my Python code in question. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Missing numpy. before `eye` and missing : at the end of the `for` line, but you example is actually working. Are you sure your error comes from there?

Answer (score 0):

As @CharlesBrunet notes, there's a few issues with the python implementation, which should be:

```
import numpy

Tf=numpy.eye(2)

n=5

f=numpy.zeros((2,n))

for i in range(n):
    f[:,i]=numpy.dot(Tf, f[:,i-1])
```

The resulting `f` is:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

You also have an issue in your matlab implementation, since you're trying to index `f(:,0)` in the first iteration of the `for` loop, which will result in an error:  `Attempted to access f(:,0); index must be a positive integer or logical`. Here's the fixed version:

```
Tf=eye(2);

n=5;

f=zeros(2,n);

for i=2:n
    f(:,i)=Tf*f(:,i-1);
end
```

The resulting `f` is:

```
f =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

In other words, other than those few typos, there doesn't seem to be any problem with each implementation. You just have to be more careful when crafting these examples, particularly when thinking of posting a question about them.

*Note that I've re-defined `n=5` so that the value of `f` doesn't take too many lines of the answer.*